# Docker php with composer PSR-4

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, psr-4

Im trying to publish my webpage using docker on my nas. But Can't get the PSR-4 to work, it wont find the controllers through the namespacing. Everything worked on my vagrant box. But as long as I don't extend a class it wont break

> Whoops \ Exception \ ErrorException (E_ERROR) Class
>   'Rsubscribe\Controllers\BaseController' not found

**bootstrap/start.php**

```
require(__DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php");
session_start();  
$router = new AltoRouter();
```

**BaseController**

```
<?php
namespace Rsubscribe\Controllers;

use duncan3dc\Laravel\BladeInstance;

class BaseController{
    protected $blade;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->blade = new BladeInstance("/var/www/views", "/var/www/cache/views");
    }
}
```

**PageController**

```
class PageController extends BaseController
{
    public function getShowHomePage()
    {
        echo $this->blade->render("home");
    }

    public function getMoviePage()
    {
        echo $this->blade->render('movies');
    }
}
```

**Routes:**

```
<?php        
    use duncan3dc\Laravel\BladeInstance; // Temp
    $router->map("GET", "/", "Rsubscribe\controllers\PageController@getShowHomePage", "home");
    $router->map("GET", "/home", "Rsubscribe\controllers\PageController@getShowHomePage", "home_2");
    $router->map("GET", "/movies", "Rsubscribe\controllers\PageController@getMoviePage", "movies");
```

**composer.json**

```
 .....
 .....
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Rsubscribe\\": "src/"}
    }
```

Comment: Did you run composer update/install ?

Comment: yes, already done that

Comment: I only get it to work if i go through my route file without the controllers, but that I dont want to.

Comment: can you post the namespace & use part of PageController as well pls?

Comment: found what the problem was right now, the namespace of the controller had to be lowercase as the folder name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the namespace was Case sensitivity running on linux server but not when running on my osx machine for some reason. The folders is in lowercase and must therefore be lowercase in the namespaces too.